# Issue accessing SharePoint list data using SSRS 2008

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, wss-3.0, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to access list data using SSRS 2008.

I have created an XML data source with the following connection string: 
"http://[Your_Site_Name]/_vti_bin/lists.asmx".

I then created a dataset with the following query:

`<Query> 
<SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction> 
<Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems"> 
<Parameters> 
    <Parameter Name="listName"> 
       <DefaultValue>Your_List_Name</DefaultValue>
    </Parameter> 
</Parameters> 
</Method>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>`

Now the problem:

I'm having issues reading column values that have html markup/tags(specifically "Mulitple lines of text" field type). Reporting Services creates a field called “row” in the Dataset when it encounters one such column.

I tried deleting this “row” field and created the actual field manually. I then set the column value as HTML in the placeholder properties (a new feature in SSRS 2008 where HTML markup is treated as styles) but did not work.

For e.g. Comments column in "Issue Tracking List" is stored as a "div"

Executing the same query in CAMLBuilder works perfectly, showing up all columns.

How do I get over this issue. Any help?

Thanks in advance

**PS:** I have posted the same query on MSDN SQL Server Reporting Service Forum. Here is the [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/332ce140-1e8b-4e69-b29c-60f516caf5cd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same query on MSDN SQL Server Reporting Service Forum. Here is the [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/332ce140-1e8b-4e69-b29c-60f516caf5cd). MSFT moderator has found a solution for this issue.